# What is the best tool for working with oracle db?

Tags: software-recommendation, oracle

What is the best data management application for working with oracle db?

Comment: Maybe you could be a bit more detailed about what you are looking for? What whould that tool be capable of?

Answer (score 1):

> Oracle SQL Developer

There is no debian installation file for it though so [start here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) and accept the license.

> Installation

- Ensure you have a JDK installed, if not, you can [download one here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- [Download the zip file](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).
- Unzip sqldeveloper.zip
- cd sqldeveloper/
- sh sqldeveloper